# Casting a string value type to System.Windows.Forms.Label Class

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, casting

> **NOTE**
>
> I am supporting the idea that the below issue is way impossible to do.
>   Pls, do not misunderstand me.
>   It is not me. Please read the question carefully.

I have involved a discussion about casting `string` value type to `System.Windows.Forms.Label` Class. Other guys have supported that it is possible but for me, it is impossible with current release of C#.

Am I missing something? The guy is trying the following code;

> **NOTE-2**
>
> The below code is not written by me !

```
lbl=((Label)("label"+"1"));
```

I don't know that I am being just ignorant but it is so impossible for me that it can be even done by Jon Skeet.

what is the deal here?

Comment: Have you got a reference to that discussion? I don't understand why you think this would be possible "out of the box".

Comment: @RB you misunderstand me. I am supporting the idea that it is way impossible. The dissuasion has taken place in a Turkish discussion forum in Turkish : http://forum.yazgelistir.com/topic.aspx?topicid=22561&siteid=0&forumid=3

Comment: Thanks to Google Translate, I am reading turkish! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that code could work is by creating a [casting operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx), however they have to define that within the type declaration, and neither `string` nor `Label` have such a casting operator.

---

Do they want to get the label on their form called label1?

If so, they can use the `FindControl` of `Page`, or the control that the label is placed on.

Comment: NO, he wants to know is it possible to cast label control from string.

Comment: God, thanks @Reniuz. Furthermore, I am supporting the idea that it is impossible.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that. They try to find the control inside the windows form control.

Comment: @tugberk, then they can use my suggestion.

Comment: You say in your comment *Windows Form*, however in your question you said `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label`, which are they using? (will edit my answer if appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to cast a String to Label.

You could try something like this, but it is not a cast.

```
lbl = new Label() { Text = "Label" + "1" };
```